# Python - Unsupported Operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python

I'm attempting to find the average of a list within a list.
My code :

```
Scores=[['James','Q',3,4,1,5],['Kat','L',3,4,1,2],['Maddy','G',3,5,6,4],['John','K',3,7,6,8],['Filip','NJ',3,8,9,9]]
size=len(Scores[3:5])
total=sum(Scores[3:5])
meanAverage=total/size
print(meanAverage)
```

The error I get is:

```
    total=sum(Scores[3:5])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

Comment: Minimal reproduction: `0 + []` (where 0 is the default sum accumulator value). It doesn't make sense. Go back and review the data (ie. the result of the slice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop over your list, and attempt to apply the `sum` function on the last 4 items of sub-lists:

```
>>> [sum(i[3:5])/4 for i in Scores]
[1.25, 1.25, 2.75, 3.25, 4.25]
```

But note that if you want to get the number you need `[2:6]` slicing :

```
>>> [(i[2:6]) for i in Scores]
[[3, 4, 1, 5], [3, 4, 1, 2], [3, 5, 6, 4], [3, 7, 6, 8], [3, 8, 9, 9]]
>>> [sum(i[2:6])/4 for i in Scores]
[3.25, 2.5, 4.5, 6.0, 7.25]
```

Comment: Are the decimals outputted the correct averages? it doesn't seem so.

Comment: @UserIsMe for the first one as the length of `i[3:5]` is 2 divide by 4 doesn't  get the avg!!! you need to use the second solution!

Answer (score 1):

`scores[3:5]` is looking up a slice from a list of lists. You want something like `scores[0][3:5]`.